# Timer in Task not firing

Tags: c#, timer, task, parallel.foreach

The following code is called from a Task t = new task(() => StartScanAsync(path));
but the timer Event is not firing, the Timer is started in StartTimer.

```
private void StartScanAsync(string path)
{
    StartTimer();
    foreach (string fsPath in Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories, true))
    {
        Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.FileInfo finfo = new Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.FileInfo(fsPath);
        fileClass.AddFile(finfo);
        //  UpdateStatus(fsPath);
        UpdateTotalFilesScanned();
        TotalFileSize += finfo.Length;
        UpdateTotalFileSize(TotalFileSize);
        IdentifyFileType.FileType ft = FileType.LoadPathRet(fsPath);
        //  Application.DoEvents();
    }
    UpdateStatus("Done Scanning.");
    StopTimer();
}
```

I tried a Parrallel.ForEach as well and have the same problem.

The following code is supposed to start a timer, run the Parrallel.ForEach over a large collection and then stop the Timer. However, the Timer event is not being Fired... Any ideas why and how to solve this?

```
StartTimer();
Parallel.ForEach(Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories), fsPath =>
{
    Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.FileInfo finfo = new Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.FileInfo(fsPath);
    fileClass.AddFile(finfo);
    UpdateStatus(fsPath);
    UpdateTotalFilesScanned();
    TotalFileSize += finfo.Length;
    UpdateTotalFileSize(TotalFileSize);
    // IdentifyFileType.FileType ft = FileType.LoadPathRet(fsPath);
    Application.DoEvents();
});
StopTimer();
```

The First code works when not in a Task, and the second code is not run in a Task but still does not work.

So To Clarify:
Question 1) Why does the timer (System.Windows.Forms.Timer (I think)) Not fire in a Task, and also does not fire when surrounding a Parallel.ForEach?

Question 2) How can I raise a Tick every second (to get Files Scanned Per Second) within the Parallel.ForEach task and the Task<> task?

Comment: Just to make sure, do you actually `Start()` the `Task` afterwards?

Comment: Yes the task is started. Even though it wasn't the Tick Event would fire.

Answer (score 7):

.NET offers quite a few different timers. You can find a detailed list and explanation in this article about [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

The problem is that you are using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which should only be used on the UI thread. In a test scenario using this timer won't work even for such a simple case:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var timer = new Timer { Enabled = true, Interval = 1000 };
    timer.Tick += (s, e) => 
        Console.WriteLine("This will never be written to the console!");
});
```

I'm assuming that you create the timer or modify its properties in the `StartTimer` or `StopTimer` methods. Even if you create the timer on the UI thread you actually have to set `Interval` and `Enabled` on the same UI thread too.

Since you are using the timers in different tasks (by using a Task or Parallel.For) you have to use a different timer, e.g. the [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Your second case could be same, but it's hard to tell without knowing the code that calls the code snippet with the parallel loop.

Comment: Shall try that today.